# Backbone routing regex

Tags: backbone.js

Trying to get my head around sorting this routing regex out, so:

```
'quotes(/:action)': 'quotes',
'quotes/:id(/:params)': 'quotesEdit'
```

Two URLs:

```
http://domain.com/#quotes/action=showModal
http://domain.com/#quotes/123
```

My question:

How can I make sure that the URL with the `action=` matches on the first Route, but not the second? and for urls like `quotes/123` to fall through to the second Route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* make this work by over-riding `Backbone.history.loadUrl` with your special-cases. Essentially, you would be skipping matched routes based on the url parameters...but that seems awfully hack-ish.

An option is to declare a single route and branch on the arguments:

```
'quotes(/:id)(/:params)': 'quotes'

quotes:function(id,params) {
  if (id && id.match(/^\d+$/)) { // if id is a number
    this.quotesEdit(id,params);
  }
  else {
    // your quotes logic
  }
```

Instead of the above, you may want to look into changing your routes a bit and your problem is longer an issue.

```
'quotes(/:action)'          : 'quotes',
'quotes/edit/:id(/:params)' : 'quotesEdit'
```

Answer (score 8):

try to add routes directly via router`s initialize

```
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.route(/^quotes\/([0-9]+)$/, "ids");
        this.route(/^quotes\/action=(.*)$/, "act");
    },
    ids: function(id){
        alert('id='+id);
    },
    act: function(act){
        alert('act='+act);
    },
```