# Backbone router with regex and extend

Tags: regex, backbone.js, backbone-routing

When googling, I see lots of examples like this:

```
App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
      '': 'index',
      'show/:id': 'show'
  },

  index: function(){
      $(document.body).append("Index route has been called..");
  },
  show: function(id){
      $(document.body).append("Show route with id: "   id);
  }
});
```

How would this implementation look like using regex?

I want something like:

```
App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
      '': 'index',
      /show/(\d+:id)/: 'show'
      /show/([A-Za-z]+:other)/: 'showSpecial'
  },
```

where the first regex matches `/show/[any number]` and passes that number in the `id` parameter to the `show` function.

and where the second regex matches `/show/[any word]` and passes that word in the `other` parameter to the `showSpecial` function.

Comment: Check this one [Backbone routing regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18061925/backbone-routing-regex)

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this syntax will work:

```
App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
      '': 'index',
      /show/(\d+:id)/: 'show'
      /show/([A-Za-z]+:other)/: 'showSpecial'
},
```

Instead you can write it like this:

```
App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  initialize: function() {
      this.route(/^$/, 'index');
      this.route(/^show\/(\d+)$/,"show");
      this.route(/^show\/([A-Za-z]+)/, "showSpecial");
   }
})
```